# How to bind progress bar with loaded data with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap-ui progressbar](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and AngularJS $http. I perform an AJAX request which may take some time and I would like the progressbar to be synchronized with the amount of data received by angular. For example : if I expect 100Mo of data from the server, the progressbar would be 10% when Angular received 10Mo, 20% for 20Mo, and so one... I thought I could use interceptors to catch the header "Content-length", but I am not sure whether it will work or not, and even if it works, I still don't know how to catch the amount of data

Answer (score 0):

Angular only call the $http post or get success call back when it receives the response from the server.

You can use the following code to show the progress bar however for sometime. it will progress fast and with passing time, it will progress slowly. Providing a user with a fake view of the response getting from server.

```
       var timer;
        $scope.counter = 5;
        $scope.stopCounter = function () {
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
            timer = null;
        };
        $scope.startCounter = function () {
            if (timer === null) {
                updateCounter();
            }
        };
        $rootScope.$$childHead.searchOrigin = false;
        $rootScope.$$childHead.searchDestination = false;

        var updateCounter = function () {
            $scope.counter++;
            if ($scope.counter > 90) {
                timer = $timeout(updateCounter, 1000);
            } else if ($scope.counter > 95) {
                timer = $timeout(updateCounter, 3000);
            } else {
                timer = $timeout(updateCounter, 100);
            }
        };
        updateCounter();
```

Just bind the progress bar with counter variable of the scope. call the stopCounter function when the response is received in success call back or error is received in error call back. Hope that helps.